# WINDOWS 10 UEFI BOOT USB

Tags: boot

i have a fat 32  USB and windows 10 image
and wish to make the USB bootable  what the steps 
i need to take in order to make that happen?

i didnt try much as im a novice user
so any guidance would be very much appreciated

Comment: I do not quite understand how this is related to Ubuntu, could you please explain?

Comment: well im an ubuntu user... who try to make an windows10 usb stick

Comment: If UEFI hardware & Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode, this should work to create a Windows UEFI installer. But it does not have the BIOS boot files. http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media Many of the Ubuntu ISO tools now use dd or dd under the hood, but that only works with hybrid (DVD/Flash) images which Windows is not. Also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu and most Ubuntu distros have an application called usb image writer pre installed. Use that to mount the windows 10 image on to a USB drive.

Next, just insert the USB drive and boot up using the USB drive.

After that, it's a fairly simple straightforward installation process